# not " using namespace std; " gives me an unexpected error (C++)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, std

This Is my first post here. I have a question about "using namespace std;". I hope I'm posting this right, but please do tell me If I did something wrong!

**Problem: ** So the problem that occurs Is that when I remove 'using namespace std;' I get an unexpected error which gives me the following error: *"identifier 'to_string' is undefined".* So my question Is, why Is it that I get this unexpected error. (I have marked below with "<-- this part here") where the error occurs once I remove 'using namespace std;' ". Seems a bit weird to me that I'd have to declare "to_strong" beforehand, but when using namespace std; It somehow declares It for me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// class name {}
class Person
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;

public:
    Person()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor called!" << "\n";

        // (this) signals we are trying to access the veriables of private
        this->name = "N/A"; 
        this->age = 0;
    }

    ~Person() // Destructor is a member function which destructs or deletes an object.
    {
        std::cout << "Destrouctor called!" << "\n";
    }

    // Accessors (Getters)
    const std::string& getName() const { return this->name; }
    const int& getAge() const { return this->age; }

    // Modifiers (Setters)
    void setName(const std::string name) { this->name = name; }
    void setAge(const int age) { this->age = age; }

    // Functions
    const std::string toString() const
    {
        return "Name: " + this->name + " Age: " + to_string(this->age); <-- This part here
    }
};
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace, Haha, ok! I'll make sure not to sign next time, thanks for the tip!. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
std::to_string()
```

std:: means standard namespace

Comment: Oh! haha, that explains It. Thanks! Been thinking about this for almost an hour now, and such a simple miss was the problem. Thanks for the help! :)